# In yaml are spaces accepted between a key and its colon?

Tags: docker-compose, layout, yaml

For example, from a docker compose file

```
services:
    cool:
        container_name: coolas
        image         : repo/cool:latest
        restart       : unless-stopped
        ports         : 
            - "6060:6060"
```

YAMLint says "Valid YAML!". Docker compose hasn't complained.

There's many questions about spaces or lack thereof **after** the colon, and some within the key, or escaping colons in the value.  There's many examples of yaml, but I didn't find any with spaces **before** the colon.

I like lining things up generally, and with syntax colouring it becomes easier to spot something out of place.  But I worry that since no-one seems to do it, maybe it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

A key-value pair in a block mapping is a [ns-l-block-map-implicit-entry(n)](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#rule-ns-l-block-map-implicit-entry) in the grammar, where the key is a [ns-l-block-map-implicit-key](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#rule-ns-s-block-map-implicit-key), which can be [either one of these](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#rule-ns-s-implicit-yaml-key):

```
[154] ns-s-implicit-yaml-key(c) ::=
  ns-flow-yaml-node(0,c)
  s-separate-in-line?
  /* At most 1024 characters altogether */
[155] c-s-implicit-json-key(c) ::=
  c-flow-json-node(0,c)
  s-separate-in-line?
  /* At most 1024 characters altogether */
```

[s-separate-in-line](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#rule-s-separate-in-line) allows whitespace, hence there is whitespace allowed after the key, before the `:` that starts the value.

Whether it's a good idea or not is generally opinion-based. I would say, whitespace should either be structuring or styling, not both. A lot of whitespace that is only used for aligning items might be misread as indentation and thus makes the YAML harder to read. If I wanted to align `:` in my YAML, I would, for this reason, use YAML flow style where indentation is not structuring:

```yaml
{
  services: {
    cool: {
      container_name: coolas,
      image         : repo/cool:latest,
      restart       : unless-stopped,
      ports         : ["6060:6060"],
    },
  },
}
```

Of course, this re-introduces some JSON-like noise, which might have been the reason to use YAML in the first place.

Another relevant question would be whether you want or should use a code prettifier that makes that decision for you anyway. The merit from code prettifiers grows with the amount of people in the project.

Comment: "Whether it's a good idea or not is opinion-based" - IMO there's no easy lines to separate opinion from valuable judgement, and judgement and fact.  IMO, again, usefulness to the community should be a consideration here.  For example, I would value and find useful your opinion.

Comment: Fair enough, I edited the question.